# Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in phpmyadmin running on docker - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, docker, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

i am trying to connect my codeigniter php to phpmyadmin mysql database both running on docker container but it says `Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused` `Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.`

i am running phpmyadmin in localhost:8082
and my codeigniter is running in localhost:8080

here is my database.php config

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => '172.20.0.3',  // Use 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' for a local MySQL database
    'username' => 'root',       
    'password' => 'testpassword',
    'database' => 'sortdb',     
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',   
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally `root` is given access to only `localhost`.

You may need

```
CREATE USER  root @'172.20.0.3';
GRANT ... TO root @'172.20.0.3' ...;
```

Caution:  It is insecure to `GRANT` full privileges to root from remote hosts.